# Las medallas del sitio no tienen concordancia de género

Tags: característica-nueva, traducciones, medallas

Repasando mi medallero he observado que los nombres de muchas de las medallas asumen que la persona premiada es masculina.

No es sorprendente ya que provienen de la traducción directa de las medallas en inglés y en dicho idioma esas palabras son neutras en cuanto al género; por desgracia no es así en español, dejando un fallo de concordancia en el lenguaje para usuarios femeninos.

Estas son las medallas sobre las que debería desdoblarse el género y mi propuesta de traducción:

- <kbd>Analítico</kbd> <kbd>Analítica</kbd>
- <kbd>Arqueólogo</kbd> <kbd>Arqueóloga</kbd>
- <kbd>Autobiógrafo</kbd> <kbd>Autobiógrafa</kbd>
- <kbd>Añejo</kbd> <kbd>Añeja</kbd>
- <kbd>Benefactor</kbd> <kbd>Benefactora</kbd>
- <kbd>Conversador</kbd> <kbd>Conversadora</kbd>
- <kbd>Corrector</kbd> <kbd>Correctora</kbd>
- <kbd>Creador de sinónimos</kbd> <kbd>Creadora de sinónimos</kbd>
- <kbd>Curioso</kbd> <kbd>Curiosa</kbd>
- <kbd>Disciplinado</kbd> <kbd>Disciplinada</kbd>
- <kbd>Editor de etiquetas</kbd> <kbd>Editora de etiquetas</kbd>
- <kbd>Editor de textos</kbd> <kbd>Editora de textos</kbd>
- <kbd>Editor</kbd> <kbd>Editora</kbd>
- <kbd>Encargado</kbd> <kbd>Encargada</kbd>
- <kbd>Entendido</kbd> <kbd>Entendida</kbd>
- <kbd>Épico</kbd> <kbd>Épica</kbd>
- <kbd>Erudito</kbd> <kbd>Erudita</kbd>
- <kbd>Excavador</kbd> <kbd>Excavadora</kbd>
- <kbd>Explicador</kbd> <kbd>Explicadora</kbd>
- <kbd>Fanático</kbd> <kbd>Fanática</kbd>
- <kbd>Franco</kbd> <kbd>Franca</kbd>
- <kbd>Héroe anónimo</kbd> <kbd>Heroína anónima</kbd>
- <kbd>Iluminado</kbd> <kbd>Iluminada</kbd>
- <kbd>Iluminador</kbd> <kbd>Iluminadora</kbd>
- <kbd>Informado</kbd> <kbd>Informada</kbd>
- <kbd>Inquisidor</kbd> <kbd>Inquisidora</kbd>
- <kbd>Inversor</kbd> <kbd>Inversora</kbd>
- <kbd>Legendario</kbd> <kbd>Legendaria</kbd>
- <kbd>Organizador</kbd> <kbd>Organizadora</kbd>
- <kbd>Precognitivo</kbd> <kbd>Precognitiva</kbd>
- <kbd>Profesor</kbd> <kbd>Profesora</kbd>
- <kbd>Promotor</kbd> <kbd>Promotora</kbd>
- <kbd>Refinador</kbd> <kbd>Refinadora</kbd>
- <kbd>Revisor</kbd> <kbd>Revisora</kbd>
- <kbd>Socrático</kbd> <kbd>Socrática</kbd>
- <kbd>Taxónomo</kbd> <kbd>Taxónoma</kbd>

Por otro lado, algunas etiquetas me despiertan dudas: <kbd>Apoyador</kbd> debería ser <kbd>Apoyadora</kbd>, pero [ninguna de las dos palabras existe en el diccionario español](http://dle.rae.es/?w=apoyador) (versión RAE). Mientras que desdoblar <kbd>Custodio</kbd> en <kbd>Custodia</kbd> cambia el significado de la medalla.

Sospecho que el sistema no está preparado para hacer concordar las medallas con el género del usuario, pero hasta que se hagan los cambios pertinentes podría desdoblarse el género con el formulismo habitual de `/a` (por ejemplo <kbd>Analítico/a</kbd>).

Comment: Tienes mi apoyo. Lo único, técnicamente la solución mas sencilla y viable es la que expones en tu último punto, desdoblar los géneros con `/a` donde corresponda. Y en los casos en los que el femenino no corresponda con esa fórmula (`Custodio/a`), hay que buscar un sinónimo que aplique.

Comment: Absolutamente a favor de la propuesta.

Comment: Para la traducción de *custodio* propongo [guardián-guardiana]

Comment: me parece que la solucion de desdoblar es la mejor, ya que no tenemos forma de saber el genero de alguien. SO no lo pregunta (y la verdad ni interesa)

Comment: Pues esto dice la RAE, y estoy de acuerdo con lo que dicen, finalmente son los que dan las reglas del idioma: http://www.rae.es/consultas/los-ciudadanos-y-las-ciudadanas-los-ninos-y-las-ninas

Comment: @Shaz efectivamente, la RAE habla de los desdoblamientos artificiosos, pero en [Uso del masculino en referencia a seres de ambos sexos](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tr5x8MFOuD6DVTlDBg) dice _En los sustantivos que designan seres animados, el masculino gramatical no solo se emplea para referirse a los individuos de sexo masculino, sino también para designar la clase, esto es, a todos los individuos de la especie, sin distinción de sexos_. Aquí no hablamos de la clase en general, sino de una persona concreta en cada caso. Por tanto, sí creo pertinente que en las medallas se desdoble.

Comment: @Shaz aunque estoy de acuerdo con la RAE sobre lo artificioso de desdoblar el lenguaje, este hilo no habla de desdoblar las etiquetas para ajustarse a todas las posibilidades si no de lo opuesto: personalizar las etiquetas para que se ajusten más al individuo.

Comment: En lo personal, no tengo problemas con los etiquetados, ya que asumo que son para mi "comportamiento como usuario", y no para mí directamente :o Aun así, encuentro eficaz la última propuesta (desdoble). Para los casos "dudosos", podrían haber distintos caminos, según: a) mantenerse el masculino, especialmente cuando dicho término tiene un significado diferente al mismo en femenino; b) mantenerse el masculino en los casos en que explícitamente no exista la versión femenina del mismo; c) buscar un sinónimo que permita femenino; d) reemplazarse el adjetivo por el sustantivo pertinente.

Comment: @Jorgesys "El ingeniero" y "La ingeniero" puede ser aplicable (tengo mis dudas), pero no siempre lo es; utilizar el masculino en algunas formas femeninas rompe la concordancia de género.